# How can I save html form input data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to store the data I inserted into this html form on the server side. And afterwards I want to be able to access this data and use it in a Raspberry Pi project.
How can I do that?

```
<div class='alertBox' id='box'>
            <p id='displayDate'></p> <br>
            <form>
                <input name='Event' type='text' placeholder=' Event'> <br>
                <input type='submit' name='save' value='save'>
            </form> <br>
            <a onclick='unpop()' class='close'>Close</a> 
        </div>
```

Comment: You search for examples. For instance: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

Comment: How are you submitting data right now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQL to store the data. And afterwards, you can fetch the data again.

Like this:

```
$sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO table_name (All, the, column, names) VALUES (the, inserted, values)';
```

Fetching:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE a_column_name = user_input
```

If you're new to PHP / MYSQL, you could view / store the users input using $_POST[]; superglobal.

Like this:

```
<?php
$input = $_POST['Event'];
?>
<form method="post">
    <input name='Event' value="<?php if(isset($_POST['save'] { echo $input; } ?>" type='text' placeholder=' Event'> <br>
    <input type='submit' name='save' value='save'>
</form>
```

More information: https://www.w3schools.com/php7/php7_forms.asp

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Yes I´m new to nearly everything. So for further understanding: This website is used as a calendar and if you click on a day then there plops a window up, where you can insert the title of your appointment. I want to save this title bound to the day I inserted it and afterwards I want to read this title with a python script, which is supposed to display this appointment on a monitor threw a raspberry pi. How can I do that?

Comment: If you're new, first try to do some research by yourself. And if you can't solve your problems, do some research on your problem. And if you can't find any solution, you ask. But first do research by yourself.

Comment: so, did my answer help? And do you understand what i did?

Comment: @MaxBauer also, do you want to use PHP or another language like Python?

Comment: I do understand rarely. Where does the data get stored - Into a file? If yes, do I have to create this file first?

Comment: The data gets stored or in a MYSQL database (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)
Or in the $_POST[] superglobal. It's not a file or something. It's just a variable that has the user input.

Comment: And how can I bind this input to the date I cklicked on?

Comment: that's possible via the date(), time() & now() function. 
I don't have much knowledge about this, but here's more information: https://www.w3schools.com/php7/php7_date_time.asp

Comment: You can bind the input by adding an extra input field. with type as hidden. 
and as value you do: <?php echo time() ?>.

And of course, you give this input a name like: time or now or something like that. And you call it via the $_POST['name of the time input']

Comment: Sry but I really don´t know how to do that. I am using stack overflow since yesterday

Comment: Next to my answer that i posted, you can see a number. In this case it's 0. But if you click on the arrow upwards, you are upvoting my answer. That would help me a lot. 
You can additionally also click on the check mark underneath the arrow downwards. (Arrow downwards is downvoting, in case the answer isn't relevant or useful) The check mark is marking it as the solution.

Comment: And also if you're totally new to PHP, you can watch some video's of this youtube playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLillGF-Rfqbap2IB6ZS4BBBcYPagAjpjn